# Declaring Ruby Methods along with a menu

Tags: ruby, sftp

I've been fooling around with Ruby lately, so i decided to write an sftp client.

```
require 'net/sftp'
require 'ostruct'
require 'optparse'

class Sftp

  def parse(arguments)
    ARGV << "-h" if ARGV.empty?
    @options = OpenStruct.new

    args = OptionParser.new do |args|
      args.banner = "Usage: #{__FILE__} [options]"

      args.on("--host HOST", String,
         ) do |host|
         @options.host = host
      end

      args.on("--username USERNAME", String,
         ) do |username|
         @options.username = username
      end

      args.on("--password PASSWORD", String,
         ) do |password|
         @options.password = password
      end

      args.on("--port=PORT", Integer,
         ) do |port|
         @options.port = port
      end

      args.on("--mkdir=MAKE DIRECTORY", String,
         ) do |mkdir|
         @options.mkdir = mkdir
      end

      args.on("--rmdir=REMOVE DIRECTORY", String,
         ) do |rmdir|
         @options.rmdir = rmdir
      end

      args.on("-h", "--help", "Show help and exit") do
        puts args
        exit
      end
    end

    begin
      args.parse!(arguments)

    rescue OptionParser::MissingArgument => error
      puts "[!] ".red + error.message.bold
      exit

    rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption => error
      puts "[!] ".red + error.message.bold
      exit
    end

    def connect
      Net::SFTP.start(@options.host, @options.username, :password => @options.password, :port => @options.port) do |sftp|

        sftp.mkdir(@options.mkdir)

        puts "Creating Directory:  #{@options.mkdir}"

        sftp.rmdir(@options.rmdir)

        puts "Deleting Directory: #{@options.rmdir}"
      end
    end
  end

  def run(arguments)
    parse(arguments)
    connect
  end
end

sftp = Sftp.new
sftp.run(ARGV)
```

I want these two commands to be separated. For example when i pass
the argument mkdir I just want only this to run and if I want to run rmdir again I just wanna run only this command.

It has to do with methods, but I can't find a proper solution. And I'm really rusty.
Any recommendation?

Comment: One thing to be aware of here is that you have nested `def connect` inside the `parse` method. This is regarded as very bad practice in Ruby as it will redefine the method on the Sftp class every time the `parse`  method is called. Not only that but the `connect` method won't be available until you call `parse`.

Comment: https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#no-nested-methods

Comment: Yes @max, thanks for the tip, I'm aware of this, I just nested it accidentally,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach could be to check if the required value is set before running the command, and skip the command if the value is not set.

```
def connect
  Net::SFTP.start(@options.host, @options.username, password: @options.password, port: @options.port) do |sftp|
    if @options.mkdir
      sftp.mkdir(@options.mkdir)
      puts "Creating Directory:  #{@options.mkdir}"
    end

    if @options.rmdir
      sftp.rmdir(@options.rmdir)
      puts "Deleting Directory: #{@options.rmdir}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Just Tried it. Thanks!!!